# Is the loap for this query?

Tags: python, trelloapi

please do u have any idea about solving this issue in python:

> For an application where you enter numbers (stops with the first
> negative number entered) and divide each time the divisor obtained by
> the new number entered.
>
> How can this be programmed in Python?
>
> Example: For: 9,8,6,4,-1
>
> Results will be:
>
> 9/8
>
> (9/8)/6
>
> (9/8)/6)/4
>
> stop

When I tried with loap and `[].append` It works only 2 steps

Comment: Can you share your code? Also edit this so this looks prettier :)

Comment: What is "loap", do you mean "loop"? What is `trelloapi` and how is it related to this problem?

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Thank you For your feedbacks. I meant loop. I tried to solve it with loop, count, len , append with list but it doesn't work for all steps. The clue  is how to get a code that generate from a consecutive entrance of numbers (while they are positive) a,b,c,d,e,f......this simular dividers: a/b, a/b/c, a/b/c/d, a/b/c/d/e, a/b/c/d/e/f....